# ELANTECH Touchpad Not Working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: touchpad

I just bought a new Toshiba S50 B Satellite laptop. I installed Ubuntu 14.04. Everything works fine except the touchpad. I did xinput -list command. It shows:

`↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]`

So,Ubuntu detects there is touchpad but it is not working at all. Nothing happens with the touchpad. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

I have also tried following links:

[Ubuntu activate multi touch on elantech](http://www.evilcodingmonkey.com/2014/01/23/ubuntu-activate-multi-touch-on-elantech/)

[ElanTech TouchPad NOT detected as PS/2 in EXO NIFTY 7385](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508211/elantech-touchpad-not-detected-as-ps-2-in-exo-nifty-7385)

Comment: I am facing the same issue I tried this still no luck http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111236

Comment: Somehow it got fixed. I just did the regular Ubuntu update on my laptop today which i do everyday and voila it got fixed after the restart. It seems Ubuntu people were working on this problem and they have released a fix. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update!
Do you like your S50-B?
I'm thinking about buying one...and replace the original OS :)